# How to draw the result of git merge -no-ff using the tikz-based package gitdags?

Tags: tikz

This source

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gitdags}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \gitDAG{
    A -- {B, C} -- D
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
   commit/.style={circle, draw=green!30!blue, fill=green!20!white, thick, text=black, font=\ttfamily},
  ]

  \node (a)  [commit] {A};
  \node (c)  [commit, below right = 0.8cm of a] {C};
  \node (d)  [commit,       right = 1.3cm of a] {D};
  \draw (d) edge [->] (a)
        (d) edge [->] (c)
        (c) edge [->] (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

compiles to the following image:

[image]

How can `gitdags` (the package used to create the first image) be persuaded to draw a graph with the topology shown in the second image?

As `A` is the parent of both `C` and `D`, both `C` and `D` should be braced together following `A`. As `D` is the child of both `A` and `C`, both `A` and `C` should be braced together before `D`. Thus `C` must be braced together with `A` while at the same time being in separate braces following `A`. I don't see how this is possible.

Is there some `gitdag` syntax that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gitdags}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \gitDAG{
    A -- C[yshift=-10mm] -- D,
    A -- D
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: --no-ff DAG]

Any node in the DAG may be mentioned more than once. This solution mentions `A` once to establish its link to `D` via `C`, then mentions `A` again to establish the direct link between `A` and `D`.

By default `C` would be placed in line with `A` and `D`, so its height is manually adjusted with `yshift`.